# Django Model Validation. How would I check to see if the users inputs match a Users in the database table

Tags: django, validation, django-models

// Model class that displays the fields for the different models

```
class Users(models.Model):
    // Possible department choices
    departmentChoices = (
        ('MD', 'Math department'),
        ('ED', 'English department'),
        ('HD', 'History department'), 
        ('GD', 'Geography department'),
        ('FD', 'Finance department'),
    )

    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=23, choices=departmentChoices, primary_key=True)
```

// views login function

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        department = request.POST["department"]

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password, department=department)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, Users)
            # return the home page as the login was succesfull 
            return redirect("home.html")
        
        # User doesnt exists 
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

//return the login page again if the users login details don't match a record from the models database table

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

1. inline comments in Python start with `#` not with `//`.
2. Please don't ever store passwords in plain text. Read this please: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/

   - If your database with plaintext passwords ever gets compromised:

     - The attackers can use the passwords on your site.
     - EVEN WORSE:

       - Your users might be lazy and use the same password and email everywhere.
       - Attackers know this and usually try obtained email password combinations on other sites.
       - In that case the fact that you stored the passwords plainly readable has subjected your users to even more harm, than just their account on your site getting hacked.
   - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/
3. You might be especially interested in this section of djangos documentation about it's authentication system: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model
4. The second argument to `login` should be the instance `user`, not the model `Users`.

```py
auth.login(request, user)
```